# Connecting my sql database with netbeans using jsp for registration page

Tags: mysql, jsp, jdbc

I have created a registrartion from using jsp...previously i could retrive data and store the data into the database from the page i created but nw..imy data isnt saved into the database i dono wts wrong wid ma code so please can anyone say wts wrong n this my code...Em using Netbeans 6.0.1, Glassfishv2ur1 and window vista, mysql server 5.0..this particular code ran successfully 9 times i dono really wt happnd n it stop worrking...please sumone let me wts actually wrong

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%> 
<%@taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql"%> 
<%--      Document   : Register     
Created on : Sep 1, 2014, 12:11:02 PM     
Author     : vaish 
--%> 
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>  
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>  <
%@page import="java.sql.*,java.util.*"%> 
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%> 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html>     
<head>         
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">         <title>COURSE_REGISTRATION</title>     
</head>     
<c:set var="FirstName" value="${param.FirstName}"/>      
<c:set var="LastName" value="${param.LastName}"/>      
<c:set var="Email" value="${param.Email}"/>      
<c:set var="Password" value="${param.Password}"/>      
<c:set var="ConfrimPassword" value="${param.ConfrimPassword}"/>      
<c:set var="DateOfBirth" value="${param.DateOfBirth}"/>      
<c:set var="Age" value="${param.Age}"/>      
<c:set var="Sex" value="${param.Sex}"/>      
<c:set var="Address" value="${param.Address}"/>      
<c:set var="Country" value="${param.Country}"/>      
<c:set var="State" value="${param.State}"/>      
<c:set var="City" value="${param.City}"/>      
<c:set var="TelephoneNo" value="${param.TelephoneNo}"/>      
<c:set var="Mobile" value="${param.Mobile}"/>      
<c:set var="Course" value="${param.Course}"/>      
<c:if test="${(FirstName!=null) && (LastName !=null) && (Email !=null) &&(Password !=null) && (ConfrimPassword !=null) && (DateOfBirth !=null) && (Age !=null) && (Sex !=null) && (Address !=null) && (Country !=null) && (State !=null) && (City !=null) && (TelephoneNo !=null) &&(Mobile !=null) &&(Course !=null)}">         
<sql:update var="insertQuery" dataSource="jdbc/Registrartion_Form">             
INSERT INTO studentcouncil.register (FirstName, LastName, Email,Password, ConfrimPassword,DateOfBirth, Age, Sex, Address, Country, State, City, TelephoneNo, Mobile, Course) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);             
<sql:param value="${FirstName}"/>              
<sql:param value="${LastName}"/>              
<sql:param value="${Email}"/>              
<sql:param value="${Password}"/>              
<sql:param value="${ConfrimPassword}"/>              
<sql:param value="${DateOfBirth}"/>              
<sql:param value="${Age}"/>              
<sql:param value="${Sex}"/>              
<sql:param value="${Address}"/>              
<sql:param value="${Country}"/>              
<sql:param value="${State}"/>              
<sql:param value="${City}"/>              
<sql:param value="${TelephoneNo}"/>              
<sql:param value="${Mobile}"/>              
<sql:param value="${Course}"/>          
</sql:update>     
</c:if>     
<form method="post" action="ThankYou.jsp">         
<table>             
<tr><td>First Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="FirstName"></td></tr>             
<tr><td>Last Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="LastName"></td></tr>             
<tr><td>Email:</td><td><input type="text" name="Email"></td></tr>             
<tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="Password"></td></tr>             <tr><td>Confirm Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="ConfrimPassword"></td></tr>             <tr><td>Date Of Birth</td><td><input type="text" name="DateOfBirth"></td></tr>             <tr><td>Age:</td><td><input type="text" name="Age"></td></tr>             
<tr><td>Sex</td><td><input type="radio" name="Sex" value="Male" >Male             
<input type="radio" name="Sex" value="Female">Female</td></tr>             
<tr><td>Address:</td><td><input type="text" name="Address"></td></tr>             
<tr><td>Country</td><td><input type="text" name="Country"></td></tr>             
<tr><td>State:</td><td><input type="text" name="State"></td></tr>             
<tr><td>City</td><td><input type="text" name="City"></td></tr>             
<tr><td>Telephone No:</td><td><input type="text" name="TelephoneNo"></td></tr>             <tr><td>Mobile:</td><td><input type="text" name="Mobile"></td></tr>             
<tr><td>Course</td><td><select name="Course">                         
<option value="-1" selected>select..</option>                         
<option value="DJVT">DJVT</option>                         
<option value="ASET">ASET</option>                         
<option value="HPEG">HPEG</option>                         
<option value="EKSTH">EKSTH</option>                         
<option value="AAGGC">AAGGC</option>                         
<option value="PCB">PCB</option>             
</select></td></tr>             
<tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td></tr>         
</table>         
<input type="reset" value="Reset" name="Reset" />     
</form> 
</html>
```

Comment: what is not working? and show us the exception stacktrace from console?

Comment: Could you please show us a log file content? Path to it: <tomcat-installation-directory>/logs/catalina.out